# Manage cascade delete between 3 tier tables in EF6 Code-First

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am using EF6, I have below tables.

1. Products
2. ProductVariants
3. ProductGallery

Now each product will have multiple productvariants and each productvariants in turn will have multiple productgallery(images).

Here's how I have designed my models.

1. Products Table

```
public class ProductsDo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... With all other fields pertaining to product.

    public virtual List<ProductVariantsDo> ProductVariants { get; set; }
}
```

2. ProductVariants Table

```
public class ProductVariantsDo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    ... with all other fields pertaining to productvariants.

    public virtual ProductsDo Product { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductGalleryDo> ProductGalleries { get; set; }
}
```

3. ProductGallery Table.

```
public class ProductGalleryDo
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductVariant")]
        public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
        ... with all other fields pertaining to productgallery
        
        public virtual ProductVariantsDo ProductVariant { get; set; }

}
```

When I run the update-database command it throws error on ProductGallery with the ProductVariant foreign key, it asks to remove cascade delete. But here I fear if I remove cascade delete it will not delete all the productgallery on deleting the respective productvariant.

Can anyone tell me how can I manage the above scenario.

Comment: if you can create one of those without setting the foreign key, I think you want to make the int nullable... so use int?  for nullable on the foreignkey id.  Then it won't give you the somewhat confusing error of cascade delete.

Comment: If i mark it nullable on ProductGallery, will the gallery item be deleted on deleting the Product?

Comment: I can't say.  I never delete anything myself.  (I just mark as deleted.)